# spring3-annotation-JdbcDaoSupport

Tags: spring, jdbc, dao

Use annotation in dao

```
@Repository("testDao")
public class TestDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements BaseDao{

@Override
public Object addObject(String sqlid, Object obj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required

I do not want to use ：

```
<bean id="termsDao" class="com.manage.base.dao.impl.TestDaoImpl">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

this code set in xml， and “jdbcTemplate” has been defined in other “spring-xml”。

How to solve this problem by an annotation ：“'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required”

Comment: Workaround here: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?111432-Why-is-setDatSource()-method-in-JdbcDaoSupport-final

Answer (score 5):

You can use one of the below approaches. The first one - taking a dataSource is preferred / recommended as you don't expose a SpringFramework class in your public interface. Both will work.

```
@Repository("testDao")
public class TestDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements BaseDao{

  @Autowired
  TestDaoImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
    setDataSource(dataSource);
  }
}
```

Or

```
@Repository("testDao")
public class TestDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements BaseDao{

  @Autowired
  TestDaoImpl(JDBCTemplate template) {
    setJdbcTemplate(template);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you're using the first approach does the DataSource refer to the dataSource defined in the applicationContext.xml :<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

Comment: Yes it does. We are injecting the dataSource via the constructor arg.

Comment: i used the first option but i am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required can you help?

Comment: My applicationContext.xml has: <bean id="countryDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcCountryDAO"><property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/></bean>

Comment: Another solution is to inject template (which is thread-safe!!) instead of configuring `DaoSupport`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21992433/173149

Answer (score 0):

I even feel injecting datasource as a constructor to your DAO is a unnecessary coding step.
Why not inject datasource in Spring config XML into JDBC template and just get jdbctTemplate
object in every DAO.

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
and let your DAO extend JDBCSupport class.
```

---

```
public class PersonDao extends JdbcDaoSupport{
public List<Person> selectAll(){
    String selectAllSql = "SELECT * FROM PERSON;";

    return getJdbcTemplate().query(selectAllSql, new PersonRowMapper());
```

........
    }

}

Full example :
http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-jdbc-dao-support.jsp

Comment: JdbcDaoSupport requires jdbctemplate property to be injected. You'll get a  Runtime exception here